# Laravel 5 How to run a php file via scheduler

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1, scheduler

First time ever setting up a cron/scheduler.  How do I run a php file with the scheduler?  This is what I see in Laravel's documentation...

Entered the following command via Putty/SSH...

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now... In the Kernel.php file... do I simply add the path to the php file that I want to run in the statement below?

```
$schedule->exec('node /home/forge/script.js')->daily();
```

Comment: why bother with laravel scheduler when you not scheduling php code? use cronjob directly.

Comment: @RajKamal  I need to use Laravel Scheduler.

Comment: uhh, I think the laravel docs are pretty clear on this point. 

you need to add `$schedule->exec('node /home/forge/script.js')->daily();` to `Kernel@schedule()`. 
I don't have slightest of idea about your adding path/to/php in Kernel.php file

Answer (score 7):

After a few days... I have it working.

I set up the cron job in my cpanel.  I set it up to run every minute so I could get good feedback on what I was doing wrong.  I created a text file to record the errors.

```
php /home/accountname/artisan schedule:run >> /home/accountname/cron-output.txt 2>&1
```

I thought I had to call the php file where the method was located.  However, to call a method, you must put the full path to the method like so...

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\ParseDataFeed@parseFeed')
        ->dailyAt('15:00')
        ->sendOutputTo('cron-output.txt');
```

I hope this helps someone.